# Using generic settings to for connecting to mysql and ms sql in same app?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I'm working on converting a delphi app (which uses mysql) to a c# app, with the requirement of being able to connect to both a MySQL and MS SQL database.

The following fields in the connection string will be manually set by the user via a textbox:

```
Server, Port, DataBase, UserID, Password
```

Then I'd just assign them to the connection string:

```
connString = String.Format("Server={0}; Port={1}; DataBase={2}; Uid={3}; Pwd={4};", hostname, port, database, user, password);
```

However, MySQL and MS SQL strings are different. I can have an option that lets the user switch between two different strings depending on which database they are connecting to, but is there some generic way to switch between the two without using different connection strings and `SQLConnection` vs `MySQLConnection`?

Comment: What about: `connString = flagMySql ? String.Format("MYSQLCONNSTRING", values) : String.Format("MSSQLCONNSTRING", values);`?

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't I still need two connection strings though?

Comment: Probably, yes. I don't know if you can combine MySql conn strings with MsSql conn strings.

Comment: `<add name="DbMySqlConn" connectionString=" Data Source=MYSQLDataSrc;User Id={0};Password={1};" />
    <add name="DbSqlConn2" connectionString=" Data Source=SQLServerDataSrc;User Id={0};Password={1};" />` you could add something like this depending on what checkbox item is selected in the UI having them enter a username and password for their perspective sever account I currently do this using Oracle and Sql Server and works like a charm.. you will need 2 connection strings do not allow the user to type in a connection string too many chances for ERRORS

Comment: @pfinferno You'd need two connection string templates if that's what you mean.  Maybe you could use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` as a `DbConnectionStringBuilder` and the equivalent for MySQL if it has one.

Comment: Alright thanks for the tips guys, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The connection strings for MSSQL and MySQL can't be "merged" and parameterized to work on both dbms at the same time. Sadly both have some keywords that don't have any overlapping aliases (User Id e.g.).

Compare: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ and https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

You should consider storing templates for both somewhere (e.g. in your config) and building your connection strings with a simple function that reads the template and inserts the parameters. (As you basically already mentioned)

```
 <appSettings>  
     <add key="MySQL" value="server={0};port={1};database={2};uid={3};password={4}"/>
     <add key="MSSQL" value="data source={0}:{1};initial catalog={2};User Id={3};Password={4}; />
 </appSettings>

public string GetConString(string dbms, string server, int port, string database, string user, string password
{
    return String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[dbms], server, port, database, user, password;
}
```